# How to query: filtering on multiple primary partition keys and range on primary sort key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

**Background**
I have a dynamoDB table consisting of a Primary Partition Key `clientID` ("N") and a Primary Sort Key `createdAt`("S") (as UTC ISO 8601 date) + some additional attributes.

**Problem**
I Want to query back, all items where `createdAt BETWEEN` two dates and only for around 100 specific `clientID`s at a time.

- **Dead end 1:** First I thought about using [BatchGetItem](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html), however though I know what `clientID`s I want to query, I cannot specify the sort keys, since I'm looking for anything, that happen within a timeframe.
- **Dead end 2**: Secondly I though about using [Query](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html), however that one does not allow me to look for multiple `clientID`s at the same time (in looked at the ´IN´ operator, [but that one does not do what I was hoping for](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-document-js-sdk/issues/33)). So in other words, how can I achieve this, without having to do a `Query` for every single `ClientID` in the timeframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing something else:

I added a new attribute on called `index_date` which only holds the date part of `created_at` (not time). Then I added a new secondary global index on this attribute, with `created_at` as sort key. In this way, I can efficiently query back all items for one day (in a specific time frame if I want) at a time. Then process them afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The two options you mention, are actually the only ones you have.

- Option 1: Use BatchGetItem for required `clientID`, and then do application-side filtering on `createdAt`.
- Option 2: Fire 1 Query for each `clientID` and `createdAt` range, and then merge data on application-side.

You need to choose one of the two, depending on your access pattern, table structure and cost factor.

For e.g., if the average number of `createdAt` per `clientID` isn't high, Option 1 would be good enough, as it'll also be frugal on read capacity units.

**EDIT**: As pointed out by Niels in this answer's comment, Option 1 won't work in this particular scenario, as BatchGetItem needs both partition and sort keys.

Comment: Hmm, I cannot see how option one would work. In the documentation  it says: *"Keys - An array of primary key attribute values that define specific items in the table. For each primary key, you must provide all of the key attributes. For example, with a simple primary key, you only need to provide the partition key value. For a composite key, you must provide both the partition key value and the sort key value."* So in my case, where I don't know the `createdAt` beforehand, then it's impossible for me to do a batch get...

Comment: you are right. i have fixed my answer. so, looks like you are stuck with Query.